# Window Desktop Tools for Creating Tiled Multi-Resolution TIFFs (for IIPImage)

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff, tile, libtiff

I am trying to create Tiled Multi-Resolution TIFFs for use with [IIPImage](http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/images/). They recommend two Unix-based command line tools (VIPS and ImageMagick) for doing this.

Is there a Microsoft Windows (GUI) tool that allows me to do the same thing? Perhaps a Photoshop plug-in or some easier way I can do it on my Windows desktop.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic] page: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUI isn't really needed. When you install the [ImageMagick windows binary](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) it installs a great set of command line tools.  Simply run 'cmd' and enter the command line provided in the IIPImage documentation:

```
convert input1.jpg -define tiff:tile-geometry=256x256 -compress jpeg ptif:output.tif
```

It's probably easier than you think. I know you were interested in a GUI, but honestly it's not needed in this case. Much easier and faster using the command line.

Comment: You are right, was pretty easy. Thanks.

Comment: I would use vips instead, it's much, much faster and uses a fraction of the memory. For a 10k x 10k pixel image, I see "$ time convert wtc.jpg -define tiff:tile-geometry=256x256 -compress jpeg ptif:output.tif
real 0m23.490s
user 0m55.568s
sys 0m0.620s
peak memory: 1.5gb" vs the vips command "$ time vips copy wtc.jpg output.tif[compression=jpeg,tile,tile-width=256,tile-height=256] 
real 0m0.942s
user 0m1.568s
sys 0m0.056s
peak memory 30MB". So 25x faster, 50x less memory.